# More upload speed with multiple instances - why? (Windows -> Google Drive)

Tags: vb.net, windows, google-drive-api, file-transfer, transfer

I write a complex google drive upload manager in vb.net for windows how works really fine.
But one very strange thing is the upload speed. My uploader works with multitasking threads and each thread start a new "connection" to google drive.
But when the tool upload 10 files parallel it is much slower (half) then when my tool runs double with 5 files parallel. Each instance from my prgramm reach ~200mbps. Not more.

I know that there could be many variables. Each instance of my program reach more or less 200mps. It does not matter if my program upload in 1 or 5 threads files. Google can't throttle because I reach much more with mutliple instances of my program. Google doesn't know how many real instances of my programm runs, right ;)

I'm sure for Google Drive it's look not different so I think the Problem comes from Windows.

Any suggestions? I have no idea how to "fix" this.

Comment: There are so many variable to this, it could be your software that doesn't do it properly. It could be your ISP that throttle uploads (they usually do this to prevent ftp server/torrents). It could be google that throttle. It could be your hardware that can't handle that many threads (it's recommended to have 1 thread per cpu). ect...

Comment: As @the_lotus commented there are many variables that have influence on the upload speed. If you want to deploy your programm to many systems you can build some dynamic adjustment. E.g. start more threads until the overall upload speed degrades.

Comment: I know that there could be many variables. But I think you missanderstand my bad english a little bit.
Each instance of my program reach more or less 200mps. It does not matter if my program upload in 1 or 5 threads files. 

Google can't throttle because I reach much more with mutliple instances of my program. (Google doesn't know how many real instances of my programm runs, right ;)

Comment: @rboe E.g. start more threads until the overall upload speed degrades. 
My problem is, that the speed don't increase wirh more threads! Thats exctle the problem. 
Only a new instance of my app increase the speed.

Comment: incorrect assumption: google DOES throttle at the api key level

Comment: Now I pinpoint the error. It is google (other tools throttle at the same speed) BUT google throttle per Instance. Here the proof:
http://imgs.re/images/2016/08/24/Untitled.png
red- one instance | blue - 5 instances.

So the question is, why know google that its run on the same instance? I open for each upload a new connection token so its realy the same if I start a new thread in instance a or b.